# AngularJS directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please find below the directive which i wrote,

```
angular.module('netVogue.directives', []).
  directive('set-First-Active', function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs){
          alert('sample');
          element.addClass("active");     
      };
  });
```

I have added this directive to my module in below way,

```
angular.module('netVogue', ['netVogue.filters', 'netVogue.services', 'netVogue.directives']);
```

I used this directive in my template in following format,

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="viewPrintcampaign in viewPrintcampaigns" ng-init="first=$first" set-First-Active> 
</div>
```

However, i neither see any response of alert nor class is getting added.
Can someone please help me with this? 
Due to some dependency, i don't want to use 'ng-class' but want to add class='active' for the first element of ng-repeat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When declaring directive should has camel case name (`setFirstActive`).

See [developer guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> Directives have camel cased names such as 'ngBind'. The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind, ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Artem. Just one more query, isn't set-First-Active name possible? We have already possible directive names like ng-bind , x-ng-bind which are similar to set-First-Active.

Comment: @Abdul When you declare directive it is named 'setFirstActive'. When you invoke directive you can use 'set-first-active', 'set_first_active', 'data-first-active', 'x-first-active'.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for clarifying it once again.

Comment: Just to clarify - I believe in the reply from @ArtemAndreev, the different invocations should be `set-first-active`, `set_first_active`, `data-set-first-active`, `x-set-first-active`. Note the extra `set-` in the last two.

Comment: Have been struggling and wasted half of my day and finally got to know to use camel case name (facepalm). Thanks for this man (Y)

Comment: I spent almost 3 to 4 hours why directive is not working as I haven't provided camel case name.