# Angular routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

I just followed a tutorial about angular on youtube but i'm not able to execute the code due to an `routeProvider` problem. I tried to include the good link for *angular-route.js* but it's still doesn't work...

I show you the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>Tuto Angular</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ng-route']);

        demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                })
                .when('/view2',{
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        });

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
                {name:'John Smith', city:'Phoenix'}, 
                {name:'John Doe', city:'New York'}, 
                {name:'Jane Doe', city:'Chicago'}
            ];

            $scope.addCustomer = function (){
                $scope.customers.push(
                    { 
                        name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                        city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                    });
            };
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

When i look into the console it returns me that:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

If you have any idea you're welcome !

Comment: I think the dependency is $route and not ng-route

Comment: You were following this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ng-route']);
```

to

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

When injecting a dependency into our app module,use `camelCase` and not `snake-case`

Here, use `ngRoute` and not `ng-route`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934258/1177295

Answer (score 0):

In Angular we need to use camelCase for Dependency injection and Directive definition in java Scripts files and snake-case in the HTML pages where directive is used

Lets take if you have directive myFirstDirective in Directive defination you will use

```
demoApp.directive(myFirstDirective, function () {
return{}
});
```

In the HTMl you will use

```
<my-first-directive></my-first-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only included it inside the function. You have to inject the serivce into the config method and make sure the ng-route is included in the app references